# Can I remove 2 GFCI breakers and install a tandem if the box accepts a tandem?

Tags: circuit-breaker, gfci

I want to add a 220v 20 amp breaker to run a mini split A/c. I only have 1 space in the box left. I see there are other tandem switches in there. I also see 2 regular breakers with blue switches. I looked up and see that they are most likely GFCI breakers. I also see that they don't seem to make a tandem GFCI. So, can I install a tandem breaker, remove the 2 gfci breakers, and install gfci outlets in the wet locations? That would give me the 1 slot I need.[image]

Comment: The blue-handled breakers are not GFCI (or AFCI), as evidenced by the lack of "test" button and looking up the specs of the "Type BR115" marking. They're just from a different era than the black-handled breakers, an era when type BR breakers used color-coding for different amperages.

Comment: Are you sure the "blue" breaker on the left isn't a spare, no label?  Your two slots would be right there.

Comment: Is replacing one of the existing two-pole breakers with a quadruplex off the table?

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it odd that the circuit labeled "Range" only has a 20 amp breaker?

Comment: @FreeMan -- that breaker's a quadplex, and my bet is that the range is attached to the inner pair

Comment: Ah, yes, @ThreePhaseEel, zooming in I see handle ties are on the center pair. However, I also see the writing on the bottom left (from our perspective) that shows that it's still just 20amps. Just confused, I guess...

Comment: @FreeMan -- it's 20A on the outer poles and 40A on the inner poles (although that's a bit hard to see from the photo given)

Comment: Also, what does the outer pair of handles on the breaker labeled "Range" control?

Comment: I find that unreadable, @ThreePhaseEel, but I'll take your word for it. thanks!

Comment: Whoa, that range breaker says "Non Common Trip".  If it has a neutral *it needs common trip*.  So that's a trip to the Eaton dealer for the correct common-trip version of that quad!  While you're there get a 15/30/15 quad (common trip on interior) and replace that dryer breaker with it.  Boom, there's your 15A breakers!

Comment: Thank you for the info. The blue breaker on the left is being used.It just isn't labeled. I guess the quad breaker on the dryer is the best to power that minisplit. I will check if it has the tab to accept the quad breaker. Thank you. I can build and repair computers, but know little about home wiring and want to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any GFCI's. Your cheapest route is to replace the blue handled 15A shed breaker with a [BR1515](https://amzn.to/3faJ58Y) and add the wires from the unmamrked 15A circuit on the left to the additional termination you just added to the shed space. That's a lot cheaper than buying any quadplex.

Comment: Thank you for your expertise!